# jQuery second contextMenu don't show properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I made this example http://jsfiddle.net/german_martin/oprkvys1/ of my problem.

I have a big div (the blue one) with a ContextMenu and inside another div (green one) with another contextmenu. Both contextmenu shows with right click.

If I make a right clic in the blue div the ContextMenu shows fine. But when I clic in the green div still appears the old contextmenu. If I refresh the page and just clic in the green div, it shows the correct contextMenu.

this is my html:

```
<div class="CuadroFondo">
    <div class="SingleItem">ITEM 1</div> 
    <div class="SingleItem">ITEM 2</div> 
    <div class="SingleItem">ITEM 3</div> 
    </div>
```

This is my js code:

```
//Centralizacion del dialog modal en la pantalla
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.CuadroFondo',
        events: {
            //Funcion para cambiarle el titulo a la opcion Seguridad en el menu flotante
            show: function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

            },
        },
        callback: function (key, options) {


            if (key == "expand") {
                alert("expand");
            }

            //se borra un desarrollador
            if (key == "creargrupo") {
                alert("creargrupo");
            }

            //Se edita la Seguridad del globo
            if (key == "seguridadgrupo") {
                alert("jejeje")
            }

        },
        items: {
            "expand": { name: "Irak", icon: "add-expand" },
            "sep1": "--MAIN MENU--",
            "creargrupo": { name: "Afganistan", icon: "crearnuevo" },


        }
    });


    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.SingleItem',
        events: {
            //Funcion para cambiarle el titulo a la opcion Seguridad en el menu flotante
            show: function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

            },
        },
        callback: function (key, options) {


            if (key == "expand") {
                alert("expand");
            }

            //se borra un desarrollador
            if (key == "creargrupo") {
                alert("creargrupo");
            }

            //Se edita la Seguridad del globo
            if (key == "seguridadgrupo") {
                alert("jejeje")
            }

        },
        items: {
            "expand": { name: "Miami", icon: "add-expand" },
            "sep1": "--SUBMENU--",
            "seguridadgrupo": { name: "Florida", icon: "seguridad" }

        }
    });


})
```

Comment: You might try a different plugin. From what I could tell, it may be a limitation with the plugin you are using. (I could be mistaken, in which case someone else is sure to correct me!) You can try: https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu which allows you to nest context menus via event.stopPropagation in the beforeOpen option.